# Ubuntu dock not shown in built in Extensions application in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell-extension, dock

Ubuntu dock is not shown in the built-in Extensions application in Ubuntu 20.04.

[image: Extensions application]

Comment: It is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: I am Upgrade Ubuntu from 18 to 20.But it doesn't show Ubuntu dock disappearing option in Extension menu.